# WordPress cache issues

Tags: php, wordpress, caching

I am using a WordPress site! when I change something in my site like CSS and image. it doesn't show in the browser but when I open that private window it shows. because of the user browser cache, how to solve that? how can I clear the user browser cache, I clear the server cache, but it remains the same. I expect when I change something on the site it will show to the customer.

Comment: Do you mean when you change it in the WP admin, or when you change it in your theme?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.